# PHP symlink returns 404 error

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, symlink

I've created a symlink like this:

```
$origpath = "../../uploads/wallpapers/".$filename;
$sympath = "../../downloads/".$filename;
symlink($origpath, $sympath);
```

The symlink is created -- I can see it browsing via FTP -- but when I use the link I get a 404 error.

I've checked my original path and it's accurate. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: what web server are you using?

Comment: You're web server doesn't allow/support symlinks?

Comment: @Pekka: That's insane, I fixed my comment as soon as I had posted it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destination path is relative to the directory the symlink is created in:

```
$origpath = "../../uploads/wallpapers/".$filename;
$sympath = "../../downloads/".$filename;
```

Means that the link points to `dirname($sympath) . '/' . $origPath`

Comment: But what if I want to put the symlink in a different directory?

Comment: just specify $origPath to an absolute path; or to a path relative to the symlink's path

Answer (score 1):

It could be turned off in Apache:

> `FollowSymLinks`
>
> The server will follow symbolic links in this directory.

If your provider allows it, you can try adding a `.htaccess` file with the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

Comment: Then this either is not the problem, or your hosting provider isn't allowing you to turn Symlink following on. I would recommend following @Arnaud's advice first, and trying to use absolute paths. If those don't work either, speak to the hosting provider